# Knowing where maps differ in their content in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, maps

I routinely work on code which generates maps as output. And as code changes, I have to ensure that the code changes produce same map output as the old code. So what I did is I serialized the desired output maps to json files and now written junit test cases which I run to see if the maps created by new code matches with the map deserialised from the json. However when it fails to match it becomes difficult to  exactly point out at which key it failed to match. For example, consider below code:

```
    def nestedmapeq1 = ["key1":"val1","key2":"val2", "key3": ["k1":"v1","k2":["v2"]]]
    def nestedmapeq2 = ["key1":"val1","key2":"val2", "key3": ["k1":"v1","k2":["v2","v3"]]]
    assert nestedmapeq1.equals(nestedmapeq2)
```

The output here is as follows:

[image]

As you can see the difference is that the nested list with key `k2` has two elements in `nestedmapeq2` while only one element in `nestedmapeq``

It simples in this case to look at the output which nested key/list has different content. But when the output is really big, say containing list of 200+ maps or say a map of 200+ keys, it becomes practically impossible to infer from the output where the difference lies.

I can write a recursive generic function to do the same, but just want to know if such neat thing already exist which can explicitly point out the list index or map key whose content differs.

(Even a Java implementation of such generic function will also do the work, if it takes two Objects as a parameter which can be both list or map and check if their contents is same or not. And if not then specifically point out where it differs.)

Comment: I don't believe such a thing already exists...

Comment: `assert` with `.equals` on `Map` does check the contents are same. Right? What is missing is just the feature which can explicitly tell exactly where content differs ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok to implement your asserting code as a unit test, try using Spock Framework.

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class Foo extends Specification {

    def 'compares two maps'() {
        given:
        def nestedMapEq1 = ['key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': ['k1': 'v1', 'k2': ['v2']]]
        def nestedMapEq2 = ['key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': ['k1': 'v1', 'k2': ['v2', 'v3']]]

        expect:
        nestedMapEq1 == nestedMapEq2
    }
}
```

The result of executing such a test:

```
Condition not satisfied:

nestedMapEq1 == nestedMapEq2
|            |  |
|            |  [key1:val1, key2:val2, key3:[k1:v1, k2:[v2, v3]]]
|            false
[key1:val1, key2:val2, key3:[k1:v1, k2:[v2]]]
<Click to see difference>

        at Foo.compares two maps(Foo.groovy:12)
```

On its own it may not be helpful enough. It gets better when you click to see difference (IntelliJ IDEA) though:

[image: the difference dialog window]